# How to architect a website or steps involved in architecting an application?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, c#-4.0, architecture

I need to know how to architect a web application. I have designed a website which is more like a buy & sell website. I designed it and coded it. It is still a beta version & I would like to know how a software architect would start this website.
Website address http://www.KashmirSouq.com

I have used ASP.Net 4.0 Membership along with profile to store certain information  and created other table which are linked to user membership table etc..

I am using MS SQL SERVER as a back end.

What I am interested in is to know how a software architect would start this website project, step by step and what design patterns should be used for this project. I need to know this for learning purpose so that I can take a professional approach in future for other projects.

**Note:** **NO ASP.Net MVC related example**

Comment: The short answer is that it depends on what kind of project it is.  If entire books have been written about it (they have) the question is too broad.

Comment: If youre starting to learn, why not start by learning MVC3 and Entity Framework 4.1? There are plenty of resources online, and personally I believe they encourage you to apply good practices!

Comment: just being detalist... I was tryong your registration page and found a state called AOL for Brazil, which doesnt exists! just a tip, btw...

Comment: You are right, I downloaded country database must be wrong in the database. Thanks i will delete AOL from Brazil. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a software architecting point,

firstly if its just a website, its merely a UI (user interface) and therefore its more of a visual design and UI concern as well and the software part that deals with it would be out of a software architect's concern i.e. network and host etc plus optimization (ofcourse without a cms in place).

Now if its a website that does require data thats dynamic or has some interactive way of dealing with data (all web is data) including cms systems etc than it does require software architecting and its technology agnostic. You can use any number of technologies to achieve your purpose be it the (.net) wisp stack, or the (php) (lamp) stack or the adobe stack or the java stack.

Yet again the important thing to understand is that web is just a view, the rest of the core of the software (I call it software rather than web) is a software architect's domain. Ofcourse there will be a seperate set of special privillage to deal with a certain UI. Web is just a UI, just as a console or a desktop program, or a mobile app is. They could all have the same underlying core but would render on all of these devices in different way presenting different UI's.

Now since your concern is about a website, there are lots of people who will suggest different architectures etc, however I would say the following other than what many people will say about going to study different technologies etc.

1. Create the most decoupled architecture possible, what I mean by that is a software that can change at will, i.e. a software that works on abstractions (interfaces or abstracts) rather than concretes. In .net framework since this question is marked in .net section you can use open source or microsoft unity for dependency etc. You will have to do a lot of reading to learn these concepts. This is also the most maintainable software design.
2. Create a data agnostic respository to access data so that you can plug in different dbs if your client needs it to be.
3. Create the most maintainable code, where things are not scattered across like magic strings but are easy modifiable.
4. Look for GOF design patterns to solve general problems.
5. Design a Service oriented architecture, access those repositories via service. Remember how you ask for a ticket from a provider of tickets and out comes the ticket, so you are the UI, ticket provider is the service. Anyone can request the ticket provided certain things are in place. These are again highly maintainable design solutions.

Platforms do inhibit these things sometimes but

In my opinion in .net framework with MVVM or MVC with regards to website (UI) fits a very best software architecture that takes these things into account. Its a long way but a better way to achieve a good architecture.

Learn about MVC here http://www.asp.net/mvc, go to forums and see how others are doing the same thing.

PS: my answers are limited to Microsoft as this question is posted under this technology.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn A LOT from the [SharpDevelop](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) project. They provide a solid foundation using industry best pratices. They even have VS templates.

> Pronounced "Sharp Architecture," this is a solid architectural
>   foundation for rapidly building maintainable web applications
>   leveraging the ASP.NET MVC framework with NHibernate. The primary
>   advantage to be sought in using any architectural framework is to
>   decrease the code one has to write while increasing the quality of the
>   end product. A framework should enable developers to spend little time
>   on infrastructure details while allowing them to focus their
>   attentions on the domain and user experience. Accordingly, S#arp
>   Architecture adheres to the following key principles:  •Focused on
>   Domain Driven Design  •Loosely coupled  •Preconfigured Infrastructure 
>   •Open Ended Presentation   The overall goal of this is to allow
>   developers to worry less about application "plumbing" and to spend
>   most of their time on adding value for the client by focusing on the
>   business logic and developing a rich user experience.

Comment: This will teach OP about that particular architecture, but not architecture in general.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I appreciate that. In my case i am using ASP.Net C#, i am not using MVC

Comment: @Student, if you are going to start with asp.net I would strongly consider asp.net mvc instead of webforms. You will find plenty of heated debate on what to chose. Here is a good objective post about this: http://weblogs.asp.net/tonylombardo/archive/2009/06/23/mvc-vs-webforms-a-clear-loser-emerging.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of excellent resources on the web about how to do this.

Here are two that I would recommend.

[http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos#ASP.NET MVC Storefront Starter Kit](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos#ASP.NET%20MVC%20Storefront%20Starter%20Kit)

http://nsk.codeplex.com/

This is the source code example for the book "Microsoft .Net Architecting Applications for the Enterprise" which is a very good read.  It introduces a whole lot of design patterns / ideas covering the data access layer, business layer and ui layer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very broad question.  But for me, I always use a 3 tier approach.

1. The top tier (presentation layer).  This would be all of your asp.net code related to the a specific user interface.
2. The middle tier (business logic).  This would be code related specific business logic.
3. The bottom tier (data layer).  This would be all of your database code.

Do a Google search on 3-tier architecture.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

Comment: I agree with you, i also use similar appropriate. A complete example for learner is always great. I will check on wiki link

Simple example with two to three table will also work for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Basically first define system level goals.

- What should your response time be?
- Should there be any kind of maintenance work in terms of data / support services that are required?
- Do you need internationalization?
- Understand the different components and understand the relationship between different components and how to separate them.
- Pick a framework for development.
- Understand your scalability requirements, this would depend your licensing costs and decisions.
- Understand your hardware and how much you can leverage it and what is the maximum. This would define bounds.

Just some points, it is a vast topic, but the ability to separate out your software and be able to scale / tune / test would be a fundamental help in any way you go.

Answer (score 0):

It is really tough to provide answer shortly of this question and it is so almost not possible to tell in a few words.

Instead I'm giving a book reference where you can find steps(step by step) application architecture guidelines, in this book the writer focuses on .NET application, so this would be a good guidelines for architecting an application, please download and see [Application Architecture Guide](http://www.flazx.us/books/12413-Microsoft-Application-Architecture-Guide-Patterns-Practices/) ( download steps: follow the link and click on "I'm Feeling Lucky" button and then click on "Microsoft Application Architecture Guide" button to start download)

Hope you'll find the way to Architect an Application.

Thanks for your time.